# How to mount the React components of a sidebar only once and after that prevent them from unmounting while changing tabs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

So my problem is, that I have a React JS app that has a Sidebar with some tabs that the users can navigate
through. Each one of these tabs makes a fetch request to Firebase Firestore where my data is stored (and if anyone here worked with Firebase you know it can become quite expensive if you don't handle the reads and all the stuff properly). So, my problem is, that every time the user navigates through the tabs, the component is unmounted and mounted again, and this triggers another request to firebase increasing the number of reads of my project a lot. So what I want to achieve is:
I want to mount all the components of the sidebar once, and when the user navigates through them i don't want to unmount any of them, is there a way to achieve this?

Here is my main.tsx file

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'
import { AuthContextProvider } from './context/AuthContextProvider.tsx'
import { SubscriptionProvider } from './context/SubscriptionContext.tsx'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(


  <AuthContextProvider>
      <SubscriptionProvider>
        <App />
      </SubscriptionProvider>
  </AuthContextProvider >

)
```

App.tsx

```
import './App.css'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';
import Sidebar from './components/component/sidebarWrapper'

import Gerador from './components/pages/gerador/Gerador'

import Home from './components/pages/Home/Home';

import Logon from './components/pages/logon/Logon'

import Login from './components/pages/logon/Login'

import Analise from './components/pages/analise/Analise'

import PasswordRecovery from './components/pages/recover/Recover';

import Crm from './components/pages/crm/Crm'

import UserConfig from './components/pages/userconfig/UserConfig'

// import Profile from './components/pages/profile/Profile';

import Error from './components/pages/errorpage/error'

import { ThemeProvider } from "@/components/component/theme-provider"

import { useAuthContext } from './hooks/useAuthContext';

import { Loader } from './components/component/loader';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Assinatura from './components/pages/billing/Assinatura';
import Templates from './components/pages/templates/Templates';

import { Toaster } from './components/ui/toaster';
import IA from './components/pages/IA/IA';
import { useSubscriptionContext } from './hooks/useSubscriptionContext';
import { MobileHome } from './components/component/MobileHome';


function App() {
  const { user, authIsReady } = useAuthContext()
  const { subscriptionDoc } = useSubscriptionContext()
  const [authReady, setAuthReady] = useState(false)


  useEffect(() => {
    // Esperar até que a autenticação esteja pronta
    if (authIsReady) {
      setAuthReady(true);
    }
  }, [authIsReady]);

  if (!authReady) {
    // Renderizar um componente de carregamento enquanto a autenticação está sendo verificada
    return <Loader />;
  }


  return (
    <ThemeProvider defaultTheme="dark" storageKey="vite-ui-theme">
      <Toaster />
      <Sidebar />
      <Router>
        {user ? (
          <>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/home" element={isMobile ? <MobileHome /> : <Home />} />
              {subscriptionDoc?.plan !== undefined ? (
                subscriptionDoc?.status !== "ACTIVE" ? (
                  <Route path="/gerador" element={<Home />} />
                ) : (
                  <Route path="/gerador" element={<Gerador />} />
                )
              ) : (
                <Route path="/gerador" element={<Gerador />} />
              )}
              <Route path="/treine-sua-ia" element={<IA />} />
              <Route path="/analise" element={<Analise />} />
              <Route path="/crm" element={<Crm />} />
              <Route path="/assinatura" element={<Assinatura />} />
              <Route path="/recover" element={<PasswordRecovery />} />
              {subscriptionDoc?.status === "ACTIVE" ? (
                <Route path="/templates" element={<Templates />} />
              ) : (
                <Route path="/templates" element={<Home />} />
              )
              }
              {/* <Route path="/perfil" element={<Profile />} /> */}


              {/* user config routes */}
              <Route path="/userconfig" element={<UserConfig />} />
              <Route path="/*" element={isMobile ? <MobileHome /> : <Home />} />
            </Routes>
          </>
        ) : (
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/entrar" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/criar-conta" element={<Logon />} />
            <Route path="/recover" element={<PasswordRecovery />} />
            <Route path="/error" element={<Error />} />
            <Route path="/*" element={<Logon />} />
          </Routes>
        )
        }
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}



export default App
```

Sidebar.tsx

```
return (
        <div className='box '>
            <aside className="flex code-hook-scroll bg-background flex-col w-64 h-screen px-5 md:py-4 lg:py-8 overflow-y-auto border-r rtl:border-r-0 rtl:border-l  dark:border-gray-700">

                <Link to="#" className='relative'>
                    <div className="flex w-22 h-16 rounded-md bg-logo">
                        <img className="w-40 logo-home -translate-y-12 -translate-x-6" src={logoPath} alt="Logo da empresa escrito 'BuildX'" />
                    </div>

                </Link>


                <div className="flex flex-col justify-between flex-1 mt-10">
                    <nav className="flex-1 -mx-3 space-y-3 ">
                        {/* <div className="relative mx-3 mb-8">
                            <span className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                                <svg className="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none">
                                    <path d="M21 21L15 15M17 10C17 13.866 13.866 17 10 17C6.13401 17 3 13.866 3 10C3 6.13401 6.13401 3 10 3C13.866 3 17 6.13401 17 10Z" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2"  ></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>

                            <Input
                                type="text"
                                className="w-full py-1.5 pl-10 pr-4 text-gray-700 bg-white border rounded-md dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-600"
                                placeholder={`Pesquisar (${searchTerm})`}
                                value={searchTerm}
                                onChange={handleSearchChange} // Adicionando a função de callback para a mudança no input
                            />
                        </div> */}


                        <Link to="/home" className="flex items-center px-3  py-2 text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-300 transform rounded-lg dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-700" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-5 h-5">
                                <path strokeLinecap="round" d="M2.25 12l8.954-8.955c.44-.439 1.152-.439 1.591 0L21.75 12M4.5 9.75v10.125c0 .621.504 1.125 1.125 1.125H9.75v-4.875c0-.621.504-1.125 1.125-1.125h2.25c.621 0 1.125.504 1.125 1.125V21h4.125c.621 0 1.125-.504 1.125-1.125V9.75M8.25 21h8.25" />
                            </svg>

                            <span className="mx-2 text-sm font-medium">Home</span>
                        </Link>


                        {/* <Link to="/gerador" className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-300 transform rounded-lg dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-700" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-5 h-5">
                                <path strokeLinecap="round" d="M3.75 3v11.25A2.25 2.25 0 006 16.5h2.25M3.75 3h-1.5m1.5 0h16.5m0 0h1.5m-1.5 0v11.25A2.25 2.25 0 0118 16.5h-2.25m-7.5 0h7.5m-7.5 0l-1 3m8.5-3l1 3m0 0l.5 1.5m-.5-1.5h-9.5m0 0l-.5 1.5m.75-9l3-3 2.148 2.148A12.061 12.061 0 0116.5 7.605" />
                            </svg>

                            <span className="mx-2 text-sm font-medium">Gerar componentes</span>
                        </Link> */}

                        <Link onClick={(e) => {
                            // Verificar se o texto é diferente de "Em breve"

                            if (subscriptionDoc?.plan !== undefined) {

                                if (subscriptionDoc?.status !== 'ACTIVE') {
                                    e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir a ação padrão do link

                                    toast({
                                        variant: "destructive",
                                        title: "Conta não permitida.",
                                        description: `Sua conta não está ATIVA, o gerador esta disponível apenas para assinantes.`,
                                        action: <ToastAction onClick={goToUpgrade} altText="Recarregar">Fazer upgrade</ToastAction>,
                                    });

                                }
                            }
                        }}

                            to="/gerador" className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-300 transform rounded-lg dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-700" >
                            <div className='flex gap-16 items-center whitespace-nowrap'>
                                <div className='flex'>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-5 h-5">
                                        <path strokeLinecap="round" d="M3.75 3v11.25A2.25 2.25 0 006 16.5h2.25M3.75 3h-1.5m1.5 0h16.5m0 0h1.5m-1.5 0v11.25A2.25 2.25 0 0118 16.5h-2.25m-7.5 0h7.5m-7.5 0l-1 3m8.5-3l1 3m0 0l.5 1.5m-.5-1.5h-9.5m0 0l-.5 1.5m.75-9l3-3 2.148 2.148A12.061 12.061 0 0116.5 7.605" />
                                    </svg>

                                    <span className="mx-2 text-sm font-medium">BUILD<span className='font-bold text-primary'>X</span>  Gen &#8482;</span>
                                </div>

                                {subscriptionDoc?.plan !== undefined ? (
                                    subscriptionDoc?.status !== "ACTIVE" && <Lock className='w-4 h-4 text-red-600' />
                                ) : (
                                    ''
                                )}


                            </div>
                        </Link>


                        <Link to="/crm" className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-300 transform rounded-lg dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-700" >
                            <svg className='w-5 h-5' viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" strokeWidth="1.5"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" strokeLinecap="round" ></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
                                <path d="M12 4H10C6.22876 4 4.34315 4 3.17157 5.17157C2 6.34315 2 8.22876 2 12C2 15.7712 2 17.6569 3.17157 18.8284C4.34315 20 6.22876 20 10 20H12M15 4.00093C18.1143 4.01004 19.7653 4.10848 20.8284 5.17157C22 6.34315 22 8.22876 22 12C22 15.7712 22 17.6569 20.8284 18.8284C19.7653 19.8915 18.1143 19.99 15 19.9991" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round"></path>
                                <path d="M9 12C9 12.5523 8.55228 13 8 13C7.44772 13 7 12.5523 7 12C7 11.4477 7.44772 11 8 11C8.55228 11 9 11.4477 9 12Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                                <path d="M13 12C13 12.5523 12.5523 13 12 13C11.4477 13 11 12.5523 11 12C11 11.4477 11.4477 11 12 11C12.5523 11 13 11.4477 13 12Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                                <path d="M15 2V22" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="1.5" strokeLinecap="round"></path> </g></svg>

                            <span className="mx-2 text-sm font-medium">Gestão</span>
                        </Link>

                        <Link
                            to="/treine-sua-ia"
                            className='flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-300 transform rounded-lg dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-700 '
                            onMouseEnter={() => setTreinarText('Em breve')}
                            onMouseLeave={() => setTreinarText('Treinar IA (Scrap docs)')}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                // Verificar se o texto é diferente de "Em breve"
                                if (treinarText === 'Em breve') {
                                    e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir a ação padrão do link
                                    // Adicionar lógica adicional, se necessário
                                }
                            }}
                        >
                            <BrainCog className='w-5 h-5' />

                            <span className="mx-2 text-sm font-medium">{treinarText}</span>
                        </Link>



                        <Link
                            aria-disabled='true'
                            to="/analise"
                            className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-300 transform rounded-lg dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-700"
                            onMouseEnter={() => setAnaliseText('Em breve')}
                            onMouseLeave={() => setAnaliseText('Análise com IA')}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                // Verificar se o texto é diferente de "Em breve"
                                if (analiseText === 'Em breve') {
                                    e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir a ação padrão do link
                                    // Adicionar lógica adicional, se necessário
                                }
                            }}
                        >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-5 h-5">
                                <path strokeLinecap="round" d="M10.5 6a7.5 7.5 0 107.5 7.5h-7.5V6z" />
                                <path strokeLinecap="round" d="M13.5 10.5H21A7.5 7.5 0 0013.5 3v7.5z" />
                            </svg>

                            <span className="mx-2 text-sm font-medium">{analiseText}</span>
                        </Link>


                        <Link onClick={(e) => {
                            // Verificar se o texto é diferente de "Em breve"
                            if (subscriptionDoc?.status !== 'ACTIVE') {
                                e.preventDefault(); // Prevenir a ação padrão do link
                                toast({
                                    variant: "destructive",
                                    title: "Conta não permitida.",
                                    description: `Sua conta não está ATIVA, os templates estão disponíveis apenas para assinantes.`,
                                    action: <ToastAction onClick={goToUpgrade} altText="Recarregar">Fazer upgrade</ToastAction>,
                                });

                            }
                        }}

                            to="/templates" className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-gray-600 transition-colors duration-300 transform rounded-lg dark:text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-gray-700" >
                            <div className='flex gap-24 items-center'>
                                <div className='flex'>
                                    <svg className='w-5 h-5' viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="currentColor"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" strokeWidth="1.5"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" strokeLinecap="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier">
                                        <path d="M4.97883 9.68508C2.99294 8.89073 2 8.49355 2 8C2 7.50645 2.99294 7.10927 4.97883 6.31492L7.7873 5.19153C9.77318 4.39718 10.7661 4 12 4C13.2339 4 14.2268 4.39718 16.2127 5.19153L19.0212 6.31492C21.0071 7.10927 22 7.50645 22 8C22 8.49355 21.0071 8.89073 19.0212 9.68508L16.2127 10.8085C14.2268 11.6028 13.2339 12 12 12C10.7661 12 9.77318 11.6028 7.7873 10.8085L4.97883 9.68508Z" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="1.5"></path>
                                        <path d="M5.76613 10L4.97883 10.3149C2.99294 11.1093 2 11.5065 2 12C2 12.4935 2.99294 12.8907 4.97883 13.6851L7.7873 14.8085C9.77318 15.6028 10.7661 16 12 16C13.2339 16 14.2268 15.6028 16.2127 14.8085L19.0212 13.6851C21.0071 12.8907 22 12.4935 22 12C22 11.5065 21.0071 11.1093 19.0212 10.3149L18.2339 10" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="1.5"></path>
                                        <path d="M5.76613 14L4.97883 14.3149C2.99294 15.1093 2 15.5065 2 16C2 16.4935 2.99294 16.8907 4.97883 17.6851L7.7873 18.8085C9.77318 19.6028 10.7661 20 12 20C13.2339 20 14.2268 19.6028 16.2127 18.8085L19.0212 17.6851C21.0071 16.8907 22 16.4935 22 16C22 15.5065 21.0071 15.1093 19.0212 14.3149L18.2339 14" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="1.5"></path> </g></svg>

                                    <span className="mx-2 text-sm font-medium">Templates</span>
                                </div>

                                {subscriptionDoc?.status !== "ACTIVE" && <Lock className='w-4 h-4 text-red-600' />}

                            </div>
                        </Link>



                    </nav>

                    <div className="md:mt-0 lg:mt-6">
                        <div className="p-3 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-gray-800">
                            <h2 className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white">Novidade em breve! Template de APP</h2>

                            <p className="mt-1 text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400  " title='Template completo com as funcionalidades do Firebase. Pronto para adcionar as funcionalidade do seus Saas e começar a rodar.'>
                                Template completo com as funcionalidades do Firebase. Pronto para adcionar as funcionalidade do seus Saas e começar a rodar.
                            </p>

                            <img className="object-cover w-full md:h-20 lg:h-fit mt-2 rounded-lg" src={Feature}></img>
                        </div>

                        <div className="flex items-center justify-between mt-6">
                            {user ? (
                                <a className="flex items-center gap-x-2">
                                    <img
                                        referrerPolicy="no-referrer"
                                        className="object-cover rounded-full h-7 w-7 dark:bg-muted"
                                        src={profileImage || user.photoURL || userIconDefault} // Use profileImage se existir, caso contrário, use o valor padrão
                                        alt="Imagem de perfil do usuário"
                                    />
                                    <span className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">
                                        {user.displayName}
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            ) : (
                                <p className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">Usuário não autenticado</p>
                            )}



                            <Link onClick={async () => {
                                await logout();
                            }} to="/criar-conta" className="text-gray-500 transition-colors duration-200 rotate-180 dark:text-gray-400 rtl:rotate-0 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-5 h-5">
                                    <path strokeLinecap="round" d="M15.75 9V5.25A2.25 2.25 0 0013.5 3h-6a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25 2.25v13.5A2.25 2.25 0 007.5 21h6a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25V15M12 9l-3 3m0 0l3 3m-3-3h12.75" />
                                </svg>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Home.tsx

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Sidebar>
      <>
        <div className='flex '>
          <ModeToggle></ModeToggle>
          <ThemeToggle />
          <div className='w-full p-8 pb-0 '>
            <CardsMetrics></CardsMetrics>
            <OnBoardSteps />
            <GridHome></GridHome>
            {/* <TableHistory/> */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    </Sidebar>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Here in home.tsx, inside it i have the CardsMetrics component that makes the call to firestore, below is the code that makes the call:

```
const { documents: historico } = useSubcollectionHistory({
        coll: "users",
        docId: `${userID}`,
        subcoll: "historico",
        _limit: 0,
    });
```

the function useSubcollectionHistory is a hook i created to handle the multiple uses of this call in different components to avoid rewriting all the call in different locations, below is the hook:

useSubcollectionHistory.tsx

```
export const useSubcollectionHistory = ({
  coll,
  docId,
  subcoll,
  _query,
  _orderBy,
  _limit,
}: UseSubcollectionProps) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState<DocumentData[] | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const q = useRef(_query).current;
  const ob = useRef(_orderBy).current;

  useEffect(() => {

    // Create a reference to the subcollection
    let ref: CollectionReference<DocumentData> | Query<DocumentData> = collection(
      db,
      `${coll}/${docId}/${subcoll}`
    );

    if (q) {
      ref = query(ref as CollectionReference<DocumentData>, where(q[0], q[1], q[2]));
    }

    if (ob) {
      ref = query(ref, orderBy(ob[0], ob[1]));
    }

    if (_limit) {
      ref = query(ref, limit(_limit));
    }

    const unsub: Unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      ref,
      (snapshot) => {
        const results: DocumentData[] = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          results.push({ ...(doc.data() as DocumentData), id: doc.id });
        });
          setDocuments(results);
          setError(null);
      },
      (error) => {
        setError("Could not fetch the documents." + error);
      }
    );

    // Cleanup
    return () => {unsub()};
  }, [coll, docId, subcoll, q, ob, _limit]);

  return { documents, error };
};
```

I tried using cache for this, it worked but killed the Firebase snapshot listener to keep track of real-time changes, so the fetch was made only once but the user was forced to refresh the page by himself if he wanted to see the change he made.
Also tried using the componentWillMount and componentWillUnmount to keep track of the component state but this didn't work as well (not sure if I implemented it wrong or not).

Comment: How exactly are you "navigating between tabs"? *Other than* conditionally rendering `Loader` in `App` I don't see where `Sidebar` is being unmounted/mounted. Is there some code that is continually toggling the `authReady` state? Also, why is `Home` rendering `Sidebar` again? Can you [edit] to clarify the issue and reproduction steps?

Comment: Oh sorry, i was refactoring some parts of the code and before i changed it, the Sidebar was rendered inside every component of the Sidebar, which doesnt make sense. So i put the Sidebar component in the App instead and forgot to remove from the other components. And by navigating between tabs i mean when user clicks in one of the itens of the Sidebar, if you look at the Sidebar you will see that inside it i have some <Link> tags from react-router-dom that redirects the user to "/home" for example

Comment: Ok, but `Sidebar` remains mounted in `App` while not loading, so it's not clear what you are saying is a problem with that component. Clicking the links and navigating around in the routes shouldn't effect this at all.

Comment: I have the feeling that you are really asking how to ***not*** conditionally render each routed component that has a mounting effect to query your Firebase collections. You can either lift the data calls ***up*** the ReactTree to a stable component that remains mounted and pass the data down as props, or remove the routes and unconditionally render all the components and conditionally hide them (*visually*) such that they remain mounted.

Comment: Yeah but the problem isn't with the Sidebar itself, it is with the components that Sidebar renders. Let me give you an actual example: Let's say a user clicks in the Home tab in my Sidebar, this will trigger the <Link> and redirect the user to the "/home" tab right? So, inside the Home component i have a fetch call to Firebase to render the home component based on the database info i get when fetching. Now, let's say the user wants to go to the Gestão page, he then clicks in the Gestão tab in the Sidebar and inside this component another fetch is made to firebase.

Comment: What i want to achieve is, when the user returns to the Home component by clicking in the Home tab in the Sidebar, i dont want to make the request to Firebase again.

Comment: Sidebar basically renders only links as far as I can tell. I guess it's a red herring in your post since it's now clear the actual issue is in your router/routes and the way routes are matched and conditionally render their content.

Comment: And by what i understood, this happens because when the user leaves the Home tab for example, this tab is unmounted and the Gestão tab is mounted. And after he returns to the Home tab, the Gestão tab is unmounted and the Home tab is remounted again.

Comment: Yes, that is the normal expected behavior. If the Firebase documents/collections are queried directly too often then I suppose you could implement a "middle layer" that manages the queries to the backend and caches the results for the UI, rate limit the requests based on timestamps. Or follow one of the suggestions above. Does this make sense?

Comment: "You can either lift the data calls up the ReactTree to a stable component that remains mounted and pass the data down as props" This was one of my solutions, but the problem with this is that i need to fetch the data for all components to pass the data as props, even if the user dont went to the specific page of the data

Comment: Does [this](/a/72122662/8690857) or [this](/a/52701789/8690857) or [this](/a/38423694/8690857) help answer your question?

Comment: It helped me to understand better the firebase billing, but i'm still not sure what is the best approach i should use in my case. Sorry to bother you with this for so long, i'm quite new to React so i still dont get it if there is a way to achieve the behavior i mentioned, or if i really need to use some workaround to this, and if so, what is your suggestion? Also thank you for your time and patience.